# Change size of NSStepper programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, user-interface, cocoa

Does anybody know any ways to resize NSStepper object programmatically?

I tried to change its size from Interface Builder, but any efforts was vain. So, maybe someone know any solutions or if it impossible, describe why.

In IB size fields are inactive.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: @trojanfoe of course

Comment: So that will have an impact on attempting to resize a control.  How are you trying to do it?

Comment: yes, but i can't change size from IB, 'cause it's inactive. upd: show screenshot in post

Comment: So how is this changing the size *programatically*?

Comment: @trojanfoe that's the idea of my question

Comment: @trojanfoe i really don't know, why i can't resize it, so, maybe, exist some hacks to change it

Comment: have you tried transforming the layer, it might work. Check this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_affine/dq_affine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH204-TPXREF101

Comment: You can't make a stepper larger than its image. Setting the frame and setting the bounds back (kind of) works on my non-retina display.